# When to use load balancing?

Tags: asp.net, windows, load-balancing

I am just getting in to the more intricate parts of web development. This may not be in the best place. However, when is it best to get load balancing for a web project? I understand that it depends on good design/bad design as to how many users you can get to visit a site without it REALLY effecting the performance. However, I am planning to code a new project that could potentially have a lot of users and I wondered if I should be thinking off the bat about load balancing. Opinions welcome; thanks in advance!

I should not also that the project most likely will be asp.net (webforms or mvc not yet decided) with backend of mongodb or pgsql(again still deciding).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Load balancing can also be a form of high availability. What if your web server goes down? It can take a long time to replace it.

Generally, when you need to think about throughput you are already rich because you have an enormous amount of users.

Stackoverflow is serving 10m unique users a month with a few servers (6 or so). Think about how many requests per day you had if you were constantly generating 10 HTTP responses per second for 8 hot hours: 10*3600*8=288000 page impressions per day. You *won't* have that many users soon.

And if you do, you optimize your app to 20 requests per second and CPU core which means you get 80 requests per second on a commodity server. That is *a lot*.

Adding a load balancer later is usually easy. LBs can tag each user with a cookie so they get pinned to one particular target. You app will not notice the difference. Usually.

Comment: How many simultaneous users is a good ballpark figure before moving to more than one server is a good idea?

Comment: @DanielCasserly: I don't think it's the number of users that plays role, it's average app response time.

Answer (score 7):

Is this for an e-commerce site?  If so, then the real question to ask is **"for every hour that the site is down, how much money are you losing?"**  If that number is substantial, then I would make load balancing a priority.

One of the more-important architecture decisions that I have seen affect this, is the use of session variables.  You need to be able to provide a seamless experience if your user ends-up on different servers during their visit.  Session variables won't transfer from server to server, so I would avoid using them.

I support a solution like this at work.  We run four (used to be eight) .NET e-commerce websites on three Windows 2k8 servers (backed by two primary/secondary SQL Server 2008 databases), taking somewhere around 1300 (combined) orders per day.  Each site is load-balanced, and kept "in the farm" by a keep-alive.  The nice thing about this, is that we can take one server down for maintenance without the users really noticing anything.  When we bring it back, we re-enable our replication service and our changes get pushed out to the other two servers fairly quickly.

So yes, I would recommend giving a solution like that some thought.

Comment: with 1300 orders per day, how many users ? 20.000 ? Sounds big  system.

Comment: The order data was all I really had without doing some digging.  But on a busy day (Tuesdays 10am-1pm central time) we've seen 200+ active connections on each server before.

Comment: The fourth site was http://www.labsafety.com, but it now redirects to a landing page on http://www.grainger.com ...as of this morning.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, it depends if/when load balancing should be introduced. It depends on performance and how many users you want to serve. LB also improves reliability of your app - it will not stop when one system goes crashing down. If you can see your project growing to be really big and serve lots of users I would sugest to design your application to be able to be upgraded to LB, so do not do anything non-standard. Try to steer away of home-made solutions and always follow good practice. If later on you really need LB it should not be required to change your app.

**UPDATE**

You may need to think ahead but not at a cost of complicating your application too much. Do not go paranoid and prepare everything to work lightning fast 'just in case'. For example, do not worry about sessions - session management can be easily moved to SQL Server at any time and this is the way to go with LB. Caching will also help if you hit some bottlenecks in the future but you do not need to implement it straight away - good design (stable interfaces), separation and decoupling will allow for the cache to be added later on. So again - stick to good practices, do not close doors but also do not open all of them straight away.

You may find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650667.aspx) article interesting.

Comment: Thanks that's a great link. And for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters here that may affect the one the other and slow down the performance are.

- Bandwidth
- Processing
- Synchronize

Have to do with **how many user you have**, together with **the media you won to serve**.

So if you have to serve a lot of video/files to deliver, you need many servers to deliver it. Let say that you do not have, what is the next think that need to check, the users and the processing.

From my experience **what is slow down the processing is the locking of the session**. So one big step to speed up the processing is to make a total custom session handling and your page will no lock the one the other and you can handle with out issue too many users.

Now for next step let say that you have a database that keep all the data, to gain from a load balance and many computers the trick is to make local cache of what you going to show.

So the idea is to actually avoid too much locking that make the users wait the one the other, and the second idea is to have a local cache on each different computer that is made dynamic from the main database data.

ref:
[Web app blocked while processing another web app on sharing same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426673/web-app-blocked-while-processing-another-web-app-on-sharing-same-session)

[Replacing ASP.Net's session entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989648/replacing-asp-nets-session-entirely)

[call aspx page to return an image randomly slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694117/call-aspx-page-to-return-an-image-randomly-slow)

### Always online

One more parameter is that you can make a solution that can handle the case of one server for all, and all for one :) style, where you can actually use more servers for backup reason. So if one server go off for any reason (eg for update and restart), the the rest can still work and serve.