# how to resolve high CPU usage and crash for asp.net application caused by System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, debugdiag

I have an ASP.NET application deployed on a server 4 vCPU, 10GB RAM, SSD HDD.
Looking up on NewRelic, I found the root cause to be:

**System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler**

I also, did an analysis using DebugDiag and the findings were:
The Performance Analysis shows that:

**The Top Threads By Avg CPU was:**

Thread 3428 - Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.ReadFile(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle, Byte*, Int32, Int32 ByRef, IntPtr)

**All functions in these threads      (excludes boiler-plate functions)**

System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)

Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.ReadFile(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle, Byte*, Int32, Int32 ByRef, IntPtr)

**All operations**
All functions in all operations (excludes boiler-plate functions)
System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait(Boolean, Int32, System.Object) 
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean) 
System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32) 
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitMultiple(System.Threading.WaitHandle[], Int32, Boolean, Boolean) 
System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef) 
Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.ReadFile(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle, Byte*, Int32, Int32 ByRef, IntPtr)

Please help and recommend steps for resolution.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135452/performance-issues-with-transferrequesthandler-and-beginrequest

Comment: Switching off the SessionState for most pages did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark EnableSessionState="False" on most pages or use a custom SessionState Module.

Comment: If you solve it base on my answer, is better at least write the reason of the problem (from the moment that you self answer your problem)

Comment: Actually I couldn't get the exact reason behind it. I wasn't using session object anywhere, except a couple of pages. Even then the Timeout happened on almost all my pages, I had already looked at those posts, so it wasn't new to me, but I thank you for your effort.
In the end, I got it to work, but the generic explanation for the cause is all I have.