# TransferRequestHandler performance issue

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, webserver, newrelic

I'm getting bad newrelic metrics for requests hitting /TransferRequestHandler
[image]

I'm forced to use InProc session mode because of how the application framework works.

Do you know how can I improve this?

Comment: Posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135452/performance-issues-with-transferrequesthandler-and-beginrequest show that you still need to dig further. The information showed above is just a shallow start.